# Cannot figure out how to setup AWS Cognito for Google sign-in in a flutter app

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I have an ongoing flutter project which is going to use AWS as backend service. First I am trying to get user authentication done using AWS Cognito. I want to give user option to sign in via Google. So I need to set up social identity provider in user pool. When setting up a console on console.developers.google.com we have to choose whether it is an Android app or an iOS app(and web server or web site and so on...)
Since Flutter is a cross platform framework app is going to be used by both platforms. So my question is do I have to set up Google sign up twice for android and iOS. If I do that then again it raises another problem. How do I apply two different clientID I get for two platforms in one single app client in Cognito.
Documentation by AWS and Google is not helpful/clear about these problems.

Comment: Having the same issue. So far, the best option is I guess using both firebase auth AND aws which might take some time to make it happen.

Comment: I am trying to do this with AWS amplify and this plugin "https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_aws_amplify_cognito" . So far n.o luck with that either

Comment: I personally don't prefer to use amplify. It's great for smaller projects though. This is what I've found so far. [Flutter AWS Cognito Federated Identities Login](https://gist.github.com/BerndWessels/fe85f558fe2a2ead7e94fef4babe9ead)
It's using google login with a separate package and get the id_token out of it. Then, use the openId token in Identity Credential.

Comment: @Hoon could you provide example for that ?